# how to combine results from 3 tables into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: A,B and C
they all share a common column name, "name".
I need to check if name 7 for example, is in any of them.

```
A
name 5
name 6
name 7

B
name 8 
name 9
name 10

C
name 6 
name 7
name 8 
name 9
```

would yield:

```
name 7
name 7
```

Because table A has 7 and C also has 7, so it sums them up.
What SQL would make that combination?

Comment: It's not clear. Is `7` a parameter and you want to know if it is contained in any of these tables? Or do you also need to know in which tables it was found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use *union all* to stack up the results from A, B and C:

```
select name,
       value
  from A 
 where value = 7

 union all

select name,
       value
  from B 
 where value = 7

 union all

select name,
       value
  from C 
 where value = 7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `union` to merge the tables:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  name
        ,       value
        from    A
        union all
        select  name
        ,       value
        from    B
        union all
        select  name
        ,       value
        from    C
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   value = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from A,B,C
Where A.name = 7 or B.name = 7 or C.name = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select name, value from
A inner join B on A.name = B.Name
A inner join C on A.name = C.name 
where A.value = 7 or B.value = 7 or C.value = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.name as NAME_A, B.name as NAME_B, C.name as NAME_C
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.value = A.value
LEFT JOIN C ON C.value = B.value
WHERE A.value = 7 or B.value = 7 or C.value = 7
UNION
SELECT A.name as NAME_A, B.name as NAME_B, C.name as NAME_C
FROM A
RIGHT JOIN B ON B.value = A.value
RIGHT JOIN C ON C.value = B.value
WHERE A.value = 7 or B.value = 7 or C.value = 7
```

**Example output**

```
NAME_A | NAME_B | NAME_C
7      | NULL   | 7
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also try-

```
SELECT * 
FROM A, B, C
WHERE A.name = B.name OR B.name = C.name OR C.name = A.name
```